# Does IE9 support Openlayers-3 Fullscreen-Control?

Tags: web-mapping, openlayers, internet-explorer

Does **Internet Explorer 9** support **Openlayers-3** Fullscreen-Control?
When I run my project in **IE9** it does not show the fullscreen control (**ol.control.FullScreen**), in every version of firefox i tried it worked well.

Is there support?

If not, is there a work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OL3 use the HTML5  Full Screen api to open the map in full screen. This api is not supported by IE 9, as you can see [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=Full%20Screen).

As far as I know there is no workaround.

Comment: Well, i guess I have to deal with it.